# Extend Helper, use by original name

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.3

I have a helper we use in all our CakePHP apps that I am trying to extend to include an app-specific method.  However, I'd like to refer to the helper by its original name.

e.g., instead of

```
$appSpecificHelperName->method()
```

I want to have my child class referred to by the base class name:

```
$helperName->method()
```

in the view.

Is there a way to do that?  This is specifically in Cake 1.2, but the app will be upgraded to Cake 2 or possibly 3 next year, and I'd like to know the solution for any/all version(s).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the docs:

> One common setting to use is the className option, which allows you to create aliased helpers in your views. This feature is useful when you want to replace $this->Html or another common Helper reference with a custom implementation:

```
// app/Controller/PostsController.php
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array(
        'Html' => array(
            'className' => 'MyHtml'
        )
    );
}


// app/View/Helper/MyHtmlHelper.php
App::uses('HtmlHelper', 'View/Helper');
class MyHtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper {
    // Add your code to override the core HtmlHelper
}
```